# How to stop programme from reading if -1 is entered, and calculate average accordingly

Tags: c

I'm a beginner in C, and my task is to:
Write a program that reads in an array of up to 10 integers representing peoples ages in years and calculates and prints the maximum age and the minimum age and the average age. Your program should stop reading when either the 10th number is entered or the user enters -1. If the user enters any other negative number or a value above 150, they should be warned and prompted again for a valid age.

My code can find the maximum and minimum numbers and calculate the average, as well as ensuring the value is between 0 to 150. However I can't get the programme to stop if -1 is entered. My average, minimum, and maximum also just consider that 10 values are entered, so I need help in counting the amount of values entered by the user before (/if) -1 is entered, so they can be accurate.

```
int ages[10];
int i, j;
double sum=0;

for (i=0; i<10; i++){
    printf("Enter number %d: ",i+1);
    scanf("%d", &ages[i]);
    if (ages[i]<-2 || ages[i]>150){
        printf("Invalid number, enter again: ");
            scanf("%d",&ages[i]);
        while (ages[i]==-1){
            break;
        }
    }
}

for (i=0; i<10; i++){
    sum=sum+ages[i];
}
printf("Average: %f \n", (sum/10));
int min=ages[0];
int max=ages[0];

for (j=0; j<10;j++){
    if (ages[j]>max){
       max=ages[j];
    }
    else if (ages[j]<min){
        min=ages[j];
    }
}
printf("Minimum: %d. Maximum: %d. \n", min, max);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Work from the outside in.  The condition of your main loop is “while `i` is less than 10 and `ages[i]` is not -1”.  That suggests the following structure:

```
i = 0;
do
{
  // enter data
} while ( ages[i++] != -1 && i < 10 );
```

This will loop while the last entered age is not `-1` and less than 10 entries have been accepted. When this loop exits, `i` will be the number of entries in `ages`.  For example, if you enter `-1` for the third input, `i` will be 3.  If you didn't enter `-1` for any inputs, `i` will be 10.  Then your averaging operation will be

```
for ( int j = 0; j < i; j++ )
  // sum up ages
// divide ages by i
```

For reading input, you can use another `do/while` loop:

```
do
{
  printf( "Enter a number between 0 and 150, or -1 to quit: " )
  scanf( "%d", &ages[i] )
} while ( ages[i] < -1 || ages[i] > 150 );
```

Putting that together, you get

```
int i = 0;
do
{
  do
  {
    printf( "Enter a number between 0 and 150, or -1 to quit: " );
    scanf( "%d", &ages[i] );
  } while ( ages[i] < -1 || ages[i] > 150 );
} while ( ages[i++] != -1 && i < 10 );
```

Answer (score 1):

The warning part of your code does not work correctly. The while looks completely misplaced and an if would have made sense instead of the while. In order to count actual number of inputs given, another counter would be preferred.

```
int n = 0; // Will count the actual number of inputs provided
for (i=0; i<10; i++){
    printf("Enter number %d: ",i+1);
    scanf("%d", &ages[i]);

    while (ages[i]<-2 || ages[i]>150){
        // This will loop until a valid number is entered
        // The logic here is subtle as age[i], which is checked by the while loop,
        // is changed on every iteration of the warning 
        printf("Invalid number, enter again: ");
        scanf("%d",&ages[i]);
    }

    if (ages[i] == -1) {
        break;
    }

    n += 1;
}
```

Use the n to calculate the average instead of 10. Moreover, while calculating the sum and the minimum, limit the index range i.e

Change

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
```

to

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
```

Comment: When I enter -1, the programme doesn't stop.

Comment: Can you provide the exact input given, as it seems to work fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

The `break` will simply stop the execution of the innermost loop.
In your case, this is your `while` loop.

You can convert the `while` into an `if` statement and the `break` will have the intended effects -- it will take you out of the `for` loop, effectively stopping to read numbers!

I would also restructure your code slightly for clarity, and to make it less messy for edge cases:

```c
for (i=0; i<10; i++) {
    do {
      printf("Enter number %d: ",i+1);
      scanf("%d", &ages[i]);
    } while (ages[i] < -1 || ages[i] > 150);
    if (ages[i] == -1){
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that before and it didn't work, it still works the same way as the while statement was working.

Comment: I've added a code snippet that I tested and works properly :)

Comment: Additional error: The `while (ages[i]==-1){ break; }` was inside the body of `if (ages[i]<-2 || ages[i]>150){...}` so it was never executed.

Answer (score 0):

You may use this snippet to achieve what you want.

```
int ages[10],i=0,input,flag=0,j,min,max,sum=0,avg;
do{
    printf("Enter number %d: ",i+1);
    scanf("%d",&input);
    if(input == -1){
        flag = 1;
        break;
    }else if(input < -2 || input > 150){
        printf("Invalid number\n");
        continue;
    }
    ages[i] = input;
    i++;
}while(i < 10);

// Calculating avg, min, max
min=ages[0];
max=ages[0];
for(j=0;j<i;j++){
    sum+=ages[j];
    if(ages[j] > max){
        max = ages[j];
    }else if(ages[j] < min){
        min = ages[j];
    }
}
avg = sum/i;
printf(" Max: %d, Min: %d, Avg: %d \n", max,min,avg);
```

Note `i` is only increased and `ages` array is updated when a valid age has been provided. In case `-1` has been entered then we have to exit the `do while` loop.

In case that a number  `< -2` and `> 150` has been provided, we invoke `continue` to move over next iteration without increasing `i` or assigning `ages` array a new value.

This way we ensure that our array will hold valid values. `flag` indicates whether `-1` has been provided in the loop. You may omit it if you don't need it anyway.

Comment: entering -1 stops the programme, but it doesn't read the code for calculating average, min, max

Comment: @hi_it'sme I updated my answer to include all the required parts of  OP. Please check.